# Octobercms successful mail send returns empty alert

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am a newbie to Laravel and OctoberCMS.

I have successfully set up an info request form that sends me an email via Mailgun when submitted. Submission is handled by an AJAX handler.

The problem I have is that the process opens an alert box with an empty array on the form page.

Here is the page: http://imageweaversmarketing.com/
Click on 'CONTACT' in the top-right to move to the form.

Here is the partial with the form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form data-request="onInfoRequest" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">
                    Send Message
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP AJAX:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
   public function onInfoRequest() {
   $data = ['name' => 'test from function'];
   Mail::send('mail.inforequest', $data, function ($message) {
   $message->to('fake@hidden.com', 'Roger Creasy');
   });
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I see you haven't used the data-request-success handler. That's necessary to show the output when mail is successful. Here's how I do it

```
function onSend()
{
    // Collect input
    $name = post('name');
    $email = post('email');

    // Form Validation
    $validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        throw new ApplicationException($messages->first());
    }

    // All is well -- Submit form
    $to = System\Models\MailSettings::get('sender_email');
    $params = compact('name','email');
    Mail::sendTo($to, 'temp.website::mail.newrequest', $params);
    return true;
}
```

And on the form side I used

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-request="onSend" data-request-success="alert('We have recieved your email.. we\'ll get back to you shortly')">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email ID" class="form-control input-md" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

So basically all you need is to add a data-request-success for it to work. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had to get this completed. So, I gave up on a solution within October.
I am posting what I did as a workaround, in case it is helpful to someone else.

What I did is create a route resource, and direct it to a controller to handle the form. basically I went to the Laravel base structure and handled the form through its MVC.